# Parsing HTML in web crawler

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, web-crawler

Further to my earlier question here: [Extending a basic web crawler to filter status codes and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477341/extending-a-basic-web-crawler-to-filter-status-codes-and-html-java/11478367#comment15169719_11478367) , I'm trying to extract information from HTML tags, in this case "title", with the following method:

```
public static void parsePage() throws IOException, BadLocationException 
{
    HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument();
    doc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
    Reader HTMLReader = new InputStreamReader(testURL.openConnection()
            .getInputStream());
    kit.read(HTMLReader, doc, 0);

    // Create an iterator for all HTML tags.
    ElementIterator it = new ElementIterator(doc);
    Element elem;

    while ((elem = it.next()) != null) 
    {
        if (elem.getName().equals("title")) 
        {
            System.out.println("found title tag");
        }
    }
}
```

This is working as far as telling me it's found the tags.
What I'm struggling with is how to extract the information contained after/within them.

I found this question on the site: [Help with Java Swing HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969108/help-with-java-swing-html-parsing) , however it states it will only work with well-formed HTML.
I was hoping there is another way.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out changing the method to this produces the desired result:

```
    {
            HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument();
            doc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
            Reader HTMLReader = new InputStreamReader(testURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
            kit.read(HTMLReader, doc, 0);
            String title = (String) doc.getProperty(Document.TitleProperty);
            System.out.println(title);
    }
```

I think I was off on a wild goose chase with iterator/element stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Jodd](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html)

```
Jerry jerry = jerry().enableHtmlMode().parse(html);
...
```

Or [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

```
Parser parser = new Parser(htmlInput);
CssSelectorNodeFilter cssFilter = new CssSelectorNodeFilter("title");
NodeList nodes = parser.parse(cssFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey.
Is there a way to do it without using an external library?

Comment: If you need a quick-and-dirty throw-away solution, you may extract the title using regular expressions, but, in general, avoid using regexps for HTML

Comment: Yes, I undersand that using regexps for parsing HTML is frowned upon. In this instance I only need the "title" information.

Comment: In this case, given you don't like having an additional dependency, I would go with a simple regexp.